# Filter Pandas Datafame by Another Binary Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, filter, binary

Intention: To filter dataframe with string values by another binary dataframe with 1/np.NaN. Output dataframe should only contain those string values that have 1 in corresponding binary df.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

strings_df = pd.DataFrame({'experiment_id': ['run1','run2','run3'],'2021-05-31': ['cow','dog','rat'], '2021-06-30': ['parrot', 'ranger','mouse']}).set_index('experiment_id')
binary_df = pd.DataFrame({'experiment_id': ['run1','run2','run3'],'2021-05-31': [np.NaN,1,np.NaN], '2021-06-30': [1, 1,np.NaN]}).set_index('experiment_id')
```

Required output:

```
              2021-05-31 2021-06-30
experiment_id                      
run1                 NaN     parrot
run2                 dog     ranger
run3                 NaN        NaN
```

Thank you.

Comment: What have you attempted so far? SO is not a free code-writing service.

Comment: Pavel, considered mapping string values to ints so can multiply two df, then converting back. Must be a better solution.

Comment: Can you show the code that you used? Also have you considered just passing a condition to `.loc[]`?

Comment: Sure Pavel, see as a separate post

Answer (score 0):

The below works but doesn't look very pythonic:

```
unique_str_values = list(pd.unique(strings_df.values.ravel('K')))
mapping_str_int = {}
i=1
for string in unique_str_values:
    mapping_str_int[string] = i
    i+=1

mapping_int_str = dict((v,k) for k,v in mapping_str_int.items())
strings_as_int_df = strings_df.replace(mapping_str_int)
output_int = binary_df * strings_as_int_df
output_str = output_int.replace(mapping_int_str)
```